# ssh/sftp server and force different user

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

How should I set up the `sshd_config` file to create ssh/sftp server that will:

1. allow to log in all users as usual, but on log in the user will be changed to one predefiner user `master`
2. shell and sftp access will work as usual, as if the log in was done by the `master` user

Comment: Easily achievable with shell, I think not possible with sftp. Do you consider disabling sftp and going with scp only which goes through shell?

Comment: Yes, easily with `sudo sudo -u master cmd`, but it does not work for sftp. I am looking for universal solution, where every user should be able to use shell, sftp, forwarding, just like it was logged normally as the `master` user.

Comment: Is the issue a file ownership and perms issue?  If so, you might look into mounting your volume to support acl's.  This can make sftp chroot harder to set up correctly (if you use chroot), but would facilitate writing as a specific group.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: We have several users which should be able to read/write/delete/execute all files owned by `master` user. Currently we use nfs mount with static idmap, but I was wondering if there is any simple way to "map" the SSH users which will simplify it a little bit.